# Auto numbering extra space at 10)

Tags: microsoft-word

While I was typing using auto numbering in Microsoft Word 2013, at number 10, I got  extra tabs unlike other numbers have, In example: 
 
1) test 
2) test 
3) test 
4) test 
 
9) test  
10)        test 
 
What should I do to make all the lines have the same tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to set your first tab stop to the maximum expected location of your list. In the example you've provided, you would set the tab stop to match the placement of 10)  test, forcing the previous tabs to that same alignment.

There are a number of resources on the 'net using search terms "set tabs word 2013" which explain methods to accomplish this. [One link](https://info.abtech.edu/article.php?id=463) seems quite comprehensive, although the easiest method involves the ruler.

You would type your list, then highlight the entire list. With the ruler visible, you would simply drag off the tab indicator, causing it to vanish. The next tab indicator then becomes the first and your first sections would align with 10) and would also be conveniently adjustable to your preference by dragging that second (now first) tab indicator on the ruler.